# How to fix Firefox defaulting to https for rails app on custom domain hosted on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, ssl, heroku, https

I have a ruby on rails 3 app hosted on heroku with a custom domain.  It uses oauth to allow the user to log in through Facebook.  After a user logs in through Facebook, the next time they type in our domain in Firefox (tested on FF 15.0.1 on Mac) it automatically fills in https before the address (So the user is used to typing "example.com" into the address bar and pressing ENTER, but Firefox changes that to https://www.example.com).  This of course shows the "This Connection is Untrusted" warning page (http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-untrusted-error-message) since we do not have an SSL certificate instead of loading our page.

This only seems to happen with Firefox (tested on Chrome and Safari as well).

I've tried redirecting the rails action that we point to for root to the http protocol version using this example (http://captico.com/securing-specific-routes-in-rails-3/2011/02), but that didn't work.  I've also tried adding the ssl_requirement gem (https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement) and excluding the action that we point to for the root domain, but then I just got a bad URI error.

We're in money saving mode right now as we test out the site and slowly grow in users.  I believe the best thing to do is to pay the money for our own SSL cert, as well as the $20/month to heroku to get SSL for our custom domain.  But for now, we'd like to avoid having these extra costs.

Is there a way to fix this for free?

Answer (score -1):

To fix it for free, use the *.herokuapp.com domain instead of a custom domain.

Comment: thanks, but that was an implied known option from the question ("...as well as the $20/month to heroku to get SSL for our custom domain").  any other options or cheaper ones?  we don't want to give up using our domain.  perhaps if we open a popup window to the facebook login / oauth page like a lot of sites utilize that will avoid the problem?